# How are the heights in a density histogram calculated (they don't sum up to 1)?

Tags: statistics, seaborn, gaussian

I want to visualize data by plotting distplot.

I have python code like below, but I don't understand how to calculate y-axis

Why x=2 corresponds to y=0.3, x=1 corresponds to y=0.6?
Can someone help me with the calculation formula?

```
import seaborn as sns
l = [1,3,2,1,3]
sns.distplot(l, kde=True, bins=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [probability density function (pdf in short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is only meaningful for a continuous distribution, not so for a discrete distribution, especially not when there are only a few values.

When the values are discrete, it should be avoided that the bin boundaries coincide with the values, to avoid that the values at the boundary fall quasi arbitrarily into one bin or the other.

If you set `bins=3`, 4 boundaries are calculated, evenly distributed between the minimum and the maximum x, so at `1, 1.667, 2.33, 3`.  This is not a good choice for a discrete distribution. A better choice is `0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5`. Adding the parameter `discrete=True` automatically chooses these boundaries, but only for the new version of `distplot`, namely `histplot`.

If you set `stat='density'`, total **area** of the histogram (or the kde, being an approximation for a *continuous* pdf) would be 1.  With `discrete=False`, the bins are `0.667` wide. To get an *area* of 1, the heights should sum to `1/0.667=1.5` (`sum(heights)*width = 1`). This measure doesn't make a lot of sense here (between 1 and 1.667 with probability 0.6*0.667, etc.).  For the bins with width `1`, the heights should just some to `1` (`sum(heights)*width = 1`). Here the heights mean the proportion of each value (1 with probability 0.4, 2 with probability 0.2).

The following code compares `stat='density'` for `discrete=True` vs `False`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

l = [1, 3, 2, 1, 3]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 4))
sns.histplot(l, bins=3, discrete=False, stat='density', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('the default (discrete=False)')
sns.histplot(l, bins=3, discrete=True, stat='density', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('with discrete=True')
```

[image: comparing histplot with discrete False/True]

Answer (score 2):

Please note that [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) is deprecated, use [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) instead (without **t**).

It will show the counts by default and not the **density** like in your question:

```
import seaborn as sns
l = [1,3,2,1,3]
sns.displot(l, kde=True, bins=3)
```

output:

[image]

That said, if you want to have the density (meaning that total area of the bars is 1), add the `stat='density'` parameter:

```
import seaborn as sns
l = [1,3,2,1,3]
sns.displot(l, kde=True, bins=3, stat="density")
```

[image]

Comment: "That said, if you want to have the density (meaning that the sum of all bars are 1)" is wrong — the _area_ of the bars will equal 1 with a density plot. (Notice how in your example, the sum would be ~1.5).

Comment: @mwaskom you're right, oversight from my side!